# Add "..." for a summary in C#

Tags: c#

Consider I have a part on my website which I want to show news summary. Is there any way to add three dots after specified amount of characters in C#?

Comment: Truncate the string and then concatenate "..."?

Comment: `string.Length`, `string.Substring` and the `+` operator should do the trick.

Comment: The three dots are called 'ellipsis'. Google should do the rest :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple string manipulation should suffice:

```
if (str.Length > MaxLength)
    str = str.SubString(0, MaxLength - 3) + "...";
```

Boom done.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Substring()` method of C# to get how much do you like to show and append "..." to the end.

```
string text = "Hello World, How are you? Blah blah blah blah..";
text.Substring(0,100);
```

More: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.100).aspx